# Плавный переход фона

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать плавный переход фона от цвета к прозрачному, если контента может быть и больше, а фон должен плавно переходить где-то на 20% от верха (от прозрачного)?

Должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь градиентом сделать, но переход получается грубым, если ставить 50%, то переход слишком размытый получается.

```css
.wrap {
  background: url(http://www.gettyimages.com.au/landing/assets/static_content/home/info-tabs3.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  padding-top: 50%;
}

p {
color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(12,12,13,0.6) 20%, rgba(51,51,54,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, numquam qui reiciendis aperiam, nam amet? Dolore porro recusandae deserunt pariatur eum, facilis vitae. Optio ea cupiditate iure deleniti adipisci minus.
      </p>
  </div>
```

`box-shadow: inset 0 80% 50% #000;` - Подошел бы идеально, но ведь в % нельзя задавать.

Comment: Судя по изображению, вам нужно делать градиент `wrap`, а не `p`. Должна получиться маска с градиентом поверх вашего изображения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С тенью:

```css
.wrap {
  background: url(http://www.gettyimages.com.au/landing/assets/static_content/home/info-tabs3.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  padding-top: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  
  color:#fff;
/* background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(12,12,13,0.6) 24%, rgba(51,51,54,1) 100%); */
  
  
}

span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

p:after {
 content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
}

p:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    right: -100px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -50px 50px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <p>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
      consectetur adipisicing elit. 
      Autem, numquam qui reiciendis aperiam, 
      nam amet? Dolore porro recusandae 
      deserunt pariatur eum, facilis vitae.
      Optio ea cupiditate iure deleniti 
      adipisci minus.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
      consectetur adipisicing 
      elit. Iste, quis.
      </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

А тебя не устроит маскирование изображения?

Свойство `mask` сочетает в себе изображение маски и ссылку на маску.

Первый способ заключается в использовании свойств `mask-image`, `mask-repeat`, `mask-position`, `mask-clip`, `mask-origin` и `mask-size`, которые определяются подобно частям `background` вроде `background-image`. Как и для `background-image` можно определить несколько исходников маски, каждый из них представляет собой изображение описанное в CSS3 Images. Все исходники маски будут объединены в единое изображение маски, далее оно используется чтобы замаскировать элемент и его содержимое, как описано выше. Изображение может быть в любом растровом формате вроде JPG или PNG, а также SVG или градиентом CSS. Приведённый выше пример с маской может быть просто реализован с помощью следующего кода:

```
img {
  mask-image: url(mask.svg);
}
```

Если исходник маски должен быть растянут до размера содержимого, то просто используйте универсальное свойство mask как для фона, словно вы имеете дело со свойством background.

```
img {
  mask: url(mask.svg) top left / cover;
}
```

Вторым способом является ссылка на элемент , который описан в SVG 1.1. Элемент  берёт любой графический элемент, а также группу элементов из SVG и использует их для создания изображения маски.

CSS:

```
img {
  mask: url(#masking);
}
```

HTML:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="00%" x2 ="0" y2="100%">
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="0"/>
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="masking" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect y="0.3" width="1" height=".7" fill="url(#gradient)" />
      <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".35" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
<img src="image.jpg" width="568">
```

Вот тут более подробно:

http://htmlbook.ru/blog/maskirovanie-v-css

http://css.yoksel.ru/css-and-svg-masks/

Т.е. ты заранее сформируешь маску, которую хочешь применить. Учитывая что можно использовать svg в котором маска может быть задана через проценты.

**P.S.**

Недостаток - поддержкой IE и Edge придется пожертвовать

Comment: svg, не поддерживается  в IE и Edge ????

Comment: Air, как я понял mask-image и иже с ним не поддерживаются IE и Edge
https://caniuse.com/#search=mask-image

К самим svg претензий нет - их все поддерживают

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/216596)

Comment: @alexander barakin, добавил описание

Comment: вот видишь, подробные ответы, приводят не только к отмене минуса, а еще и плюс получил...))))

Answer (score 0):

А градиент сам уже настроишь, как твоей душе угодно

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://www.gettyimages.com.au/landing/assets/static_content/home/info-tabs3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gar {
  z-index: 111;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 60%);
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 112;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="gar">
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, numquam qui reiciendis aperiam, nam amet? Dolore porro recusandae deserunt pariatur eum, facilis vitae. Optio ea cupiditate iure deleniti adipisci minus.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Это оооочень далеко от того что нужно и в том то и дело что градиент не могу настроить.

Comment: @hug  http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @hug, я не делал пример, что бы было именно так как ты хочешь.. я этого знать не могу,  это пример того, как надо сделать, чтобы добиться того, что тебе надо... а дальше сам...  ну поработай с градиентом...получиться как хочешь...